# WPF form "does not exist in namespace" error...it does though! (using GreatMaps)

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, maps, presentation

I have a project where I am trying to use a custom control. I have created a class to use for it and in the class it requires the .DLL. Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation;

namespace HackathonBaseWPF
{
    class MapControl : GMapControl
    {
    }
}
```

and in my MainWindow.xaml I use it as one of the components but it keeps saying that MapControl does not exist in the namespace, even though it auto completed to MapControl when I was typing it for the mapControl object.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="HackathonBaseWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="Base" 
        Height="895" 
        Width="1145"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:HackathonBaseWPF">
    <Grid Name="grid" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">

        <GroupBox Name="mapgroup"  Header="gmap" Margin="12,7,241,12" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <src:MapControl x:Name="mapControl" />
        </GroupBox>

    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Any ideas? I have looked at all the forum posts similar to this but not many are using custom controls with a class (not a .dll). Maybe there is a way to bypass this and just use the .dll (I am trying to integrate GreatMaps if that helps)

Comment: Is it just the designer complaining, or does it not compile? Are you perhaps missing assembly references required by GreatMaps?

Comment: I second that, check all the references needed by GreatMaps and if doesn't work, paste the exact error message you receive.

Comment: @Clemens It's just the designer, it compiles perfectly. The only issue is that it doesn't let me use the thing where I can design my ui (sorry for my lack of lingo). It just says "Invalid Markup".

Comment: Did you try to restart Visual Studio?

Comment: Yeah, many many times :/
I have also tried cleaning the solution.

Comment: @muds This is the exact error:
"The name "MapControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:HackathonBaseWPF"

Comment: I found out that if I remove ":GMapControl" from the MapControl class it works fine....Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used "Controls" as namespace name to import Mapcontrol.

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```

But you used "src" to use MapControl.

```
  <GroupBox Name="mapgroup"  Header="gmap" Margin="12,7,241,12" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">                      
<src:MapControl x:Name="mapControl" />
</GroupBox>
```

Insted of this code like

```
<GroupBox Name="mapgroup"  Header="gmap" Margin="12,7,241,12" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <Controls:MapControl x:Name="mapControl" />
    </GroupBox>
```

Comment: This is not true. The derived class `MapControl` is in namespace `HackathonBaseWPF` which is correctly mapped to the XML namespace `src`.